# How to load the map after the ajax received the data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

```
     jQuery.ajax({
      url: window.location.href,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (res) {
        data = res;
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', speedTest.init);
      },
       error: function(serverResp) {            // on ajax failure
      console.log('5xx http status code or unexpected response content');
  }
  });
```

My code is as above, if I put "**google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', speedTest.init);**" outside of the '**success:**', the chance is high that data is null when loads the map, but when I put that in '**success:**', the map won't load. So what should I deal with this matter?

Comment: Show more of your code, but basically you want to use something like the google maps API call to load in the map via JS... So call your ajax, on success import Google Maps API via JS, create a map object against the div and then add your dom event for load (which most people use '`idle` instead).. Then in that idle event, load your markers from your data.

Answer (score 0):

this code initialize map and set a marker on map that location of marker came from ajax:

```
success: function (result) {
                var json = eval('(' + result + ')');
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.320, 48.647),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });
                var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(json.items[0].lat, json.items[0].lng),
                    draggable: true
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
                    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p> Current Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(6) + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(6) + '</p>';
                });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragstart', function (evt) {
                        document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Marker Dragging...</p>';
                    });

                    map.setCenter(myMarker.position);
                    map.setZoom(13);
                    myMarker.setMap(map);
                }
```